# Is there a way to split up a variable inside an Option without having to use if statements?

Tags: rust, ownership

I want the code below to work, but since `map()` takes ownership of `Option`, and there doesn't seem to be a `clone()` function for `Option`, the following doesn't compile.

```
fn main() {
    struct ItemA {
        a: String,
        b: String,
    }
    let foo = Some(ItemA {
        a: "A String".to_owned(),
        b: "B String".to_owned(),
    });
    // OR
    // let foo = None;

    let opA: Option<String> = foo.map(|c| c.a);
    let opB: Option<String> = foo.map(|c| c.b);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:15:31
   |
14 |     let opA: Option<String> = foo.map(|c| c.a);
   |                               --- value moved here
15 |     let opB: Option<String> = foo.map(|c| c.b);
   |                               ^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `foo` has type `std::option::Option<main::ItemA>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

It would be nice if `opA` can take ownership of `ItemA.a` (so it doesn't have to clone the strings), and `opB` can take ownership of `ItemA.b`

Is this possible to do without having to use if statements to check if the `Option` is `Some` or `None`, unwrapping, and wrapping it back up individually.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `op_a` / `op_b` instead, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map_or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or_else).

```
let (opA, opB) = foo.map_or_else(
    || (None, None),
    |c| (Some(c.a), Some(c.b))
);
```

The first function is called if `foo` is `None`, and returns two `None`s. The second function is called if `foo` is `Some` and splits the members into a tuple.

Of course, this doesn't really save you much over a simple `match`, and will probably be harder to follow.

```
let (opA, opB) = match foo {
    None => (None, None),
    Some(c) => (Some(c.a), Some(c.b))
};
```

By the way, `Option` does implement `Clone`, but it requires that the contained type implements `Clone`.

Answer (score -1):

> [T]here doesn't seem to be a `clone()` function for `Option` [...]

That's wrong, [there is](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.clone), if the inner type implements `clone` as well. So in your case, just add `#[derive(Clone)]` to your `struct ItemA`.

Next, you can use [`as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) to create an `Option<&T>` and then use `map`.

```
let op_a = foo.as_ref().map(|c| &c.a);
let op_b = foo.as_ref().map(|c| &c.b);

println!("{:?}", op_a);
println!("{:?}", op_b);
```